# Can't receive frame in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am actually want to capture video through webcam.
I have explored each and every question on StackOverflow. But unable to resolve the issue.

I am using the python version 3.8
OpenCV version 4.0.1
I am using an external Webcam which is working fine.
I have also taken an online test of the webcam which was fine.
I am using Windows 10 having the environment of Jupiter notebook

First I tried this code:

```
       
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
     
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I have got the Error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Then I have tried this code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2 as cv
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        exit()
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # if frame is read correctly ret is True
        if not ret:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            break
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code Outputs:

```
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
```

It means that my program is not receiving the frames.
What do I need to do to receive the frame?

Or to make the ret True?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You `break` on the first occurence of `ret = None`. Maybe don't `break`, but rather put the `cvtColor` and `imshow` inside that `if` and test for `if ret`. So you can check, if your video stream might just has some delay.

Comment: You seem to be using different camera numbers? I think you can put `-1` as the camera number on Windows to get a list of the names of connected cameras which may help.

Comment: I am using external usb cam -1 doesn't work here.

Comment: I have tried the cvtColor and imshow inside if and test for if ret. I am getting the same error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: did you find a solution to this?, I am running into this same problem, and just stuck here